# Utilizar @babel/node en la version 7 de Babel

Tags: nodejs, express, babel

Tengo una duda muy grande, al usar Babel con un servidor express, incluyendo node,
Realizo los siguientes pasos:

```
npm init -y para generar el package.json
```

instalo nodemon y express:

```
npm i nodemon express
```

luego de eso instalo los paquetes:

```
npm i -D @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env
```

en .babelrc escribo los siguiente:

```
{
    "presets":[
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}
```

En el package.json
escribo un script nuevo:

```
"start": "nodemon --exec babel-node index.js "
```

creo un archivo index.js y en el:

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Todo Listo');
});

app.listen(8000, () => console.log('El servidor esta funcionando'));
```

cuando ejecuto por medio de

```
 npm start
```

me sale error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego al instalar babel-node en el tgranscurso de la intalacion me aparece estos mensajes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al revisar la documentación de Babel observo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

@babel/node no es recomendable, ya que es innecesariamente pesado, y la transpilación no sería la correcta.

Ayuda por favor!.
Con la versión enterior de Babel este problema no ocurria.
Gracias.

Comment: instalalo de forma global `npm install -g babel-cli`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu duda es bastante válida, sin embargo creo que está confundiendo un poco el [mensaje](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-node.html#not-meant-for-production-use) de la página oficial de [`@babel/node`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-node.html).

La traducción del mensaje sería aproximadamente la siguiente:

> **No pensado para su uso en producción**
>
> No se debería usar `babel-node` en producción. Es innecesariamente pesado, con un alto uso de memoria debido a la carga de módulos en la cache de memoria. Además, siempre se experimentará una penalidad en el rendimiento de inicio, debido a que la aplicación completa debe ser compilada sobre la marcha.

Este mensaje no dice que **no uses** `babel-node`. El mensaje sólo indica que no ha sido concebido para ambiente de producción. Por lo tanto, en un ambiente de desarrollo es totalmente válido usarlo, y yo hasta lo recomiendo.

En cuanto a la forma de hacer las cosas con  Babel 7, puedes encontrar un [ejemplo](https://github.com/babel/example-node-server) en el repositorio oficial.

Por otro lado, el mensaje del paquete deprecado `@babel/polyfill`, es simplemente un mensaje de advertencia en el que se especifica que dicho paquete ha sido deprecado en favor del uso de [`core-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js). Luego la instalación continúa sin mayores dificultades instalando las nuevas dependencias.

Yo te daré un ejemplo básico de cómo realizar las tareas que requieres en tu pregunta con los paquetes que ya has instalado.

Vamos a crear algunos `scripts` en la sección adecuada de nuestro archivo `package.json`

Además, vamos a crear una carpeta llamada `src` dentro de nuestra carpeta raíz del proyecto y toda nuestra aplicación irá dentro de la carpeta `src` (excepto los archivos `package.json`, `package-lock.json`, `.babelrc` y `.gitignore` junto con las carpetas `node_modules` y `.git`).

**package.json**

```
{
    //...
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node ./src/index.js",
        "clean": "rm -rf dist && mkdir dist",
        "build-babel": "babel -d ./dist ./src -s",
        "build": "npm run clean && npm run build-babel",
        "start": "npm run build && node ./dist/index.js"
    },
    //...
}
```

En este ejemplo puedes notar diferentes `scripts` que se utilizarán dependiendo de la tarea que desees realizar.

- `dev`: Este `script` es el que usaremos durante la etapa de desarrollo, como puedes apreciar hace la llamada a `nodemon` y ejecuta la herramienta `babel-node` la cual se encarga de compilar toda la aplicación escrita en ES6 y ejecuta luego el servidor de Node-Express. Para ejecutar este `script` solo escribes por consola: `npm run dev`.
- `clean`: Este `script` se encarga de realizar una limpieza del directorio `dist` donde se transpilará tu código de ES6 a código JS compatible con Node. En este ejemplo se usan comando de Linux (`rm` y `mkdir`), los puedes adaptar a tu plataforma de acuerdo a lo que utilices.
- `build-babel`: Este `script` realiza el llamado a `babel` y transpila el código de la carpeta `src` y lo coloca en la carpeta `dist`. Puedes leer la [documentación](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#compile-directories) para mayor información sobre el uso de la herramienta `cli` de babel.
- `build`: Este `script` es usado para llamar a los 2 anteriores, de esta forma en una sola llamada se ejecuta la limpieza del directorio y luego se transpila el código nuevo.
- `start`: Este script se encarga de llamar a `build` y luego ejecuta tu servidor usando Node desde la carpeta `dist`. Es el `script` que se debe usar en producción en caso que la distribución se realice desde el mismo sistema.

Esta es una forma adecuada y básica de usar Babel 7 en tus aplicaciones Node. Existen muchas otras formas de realizar lo mismo, cada una pensada de acuerdo a un requerimiento diferente.

Cabe destacar que para producción tampoco se debería utilizar [`nodemon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon), recuerda que dicha librería también está pensada para el ambiente de desarrollo y no de producción.

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

el único problema lo tienes en los **npm scripts**, tienes que ponerlo así

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js"
  },
```

y luego lanzar `npm run server` para que nodemon se quede escuchando los cambios y si vas a `http://localhost:8000/` verás que todo funciona correctamente

Un saludo

edit: y en el index.js tienes que cambiar la primera línea por:

`const express = require('express');`

Comment: Tienes un problema con esta respuesta. El OP claramente desea utilizar [`babel`](https://babeljs.io/) para poder ejecutar su aplicación la cual está escrita con sintaxis de [ES6](http://es6-features.org/#ValueExportImport). En tu respuesta recomiendas que cambie 1 línea de su código, pero si toda la aplicación está en ES6, entonces estás sugiriendo que reescriba toda la aplicación. Revisa tu respuesta. Saludos

Comment: No estoy sugiriendo nada, la aplicación no arranca porque tiene un problema en el `npm start`. Todo lo que tiene montado funciona perfectamente con ES6 y quizás te preguntarás, como estoy tan seguro? porque tengo la misma configuración en un proyecto, por eso me animé a responder. Un saludo